# Rouge in Rails v6 CSS failing

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails-6, rouge

Here are the steps I've taken to setup [Rouge](http://rouge.jneen.net/) in my Ruby on Rails app (following the steps listed [here](https://github.com/rouge-ruby/rouge) and [here](https://github.com/jacobsimeon/rouge-rails)).

Added `gem 'rouge'` to Gemfile.

`bundle` in terminal.

Added `@import "rouge";` to app/assets/stylesheets/application.css

Created the helper app/helpers/rouge_helper.rb with the following contents.

```
module RougeHelper
  def rouge(text, language)
    formatter = Rouge::Formatters::HTML.new(css_class: 'highlight')
    lexer = Rouge::Lexer.find(language)
    formatter.format(lexer.lex(text))
  end
end
```

Added `<%= raw rouge("def rouge_me\n  puts 'hey!'\nend", "ruby") %>` to my view.

The page loads with no errors and the HTML of the text is formatted as follows. However inspect isn't revealing any styles being applied by the generated classes ("k", "nf", "nb" and "s1").

```
<span class="k">def</span> 
<span class="nf">rouge_me</span>
  <span class="nb">puts</span> 
<span class="s1">'hey!'</span>
<span class="k">end</span>
```

How do I get these styles applied?